# How to Pause a Background Thread in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading

In my Swift code I have a process that's running on a secondary thread. In it there is a recursive method that I would like to pause every once in a while for a second or less. I was hoping I could just say sleep(0.5) but of course that would be too easy. BTW, anyone wanting to tell me that pausing is bad needn't bother. I'm aware of the various issues.

The process is kicked off with `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { }`

It makes a callback for some UI calls which are done in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Does anyone have a nice little way to suspend and resume a thread at a specific point in the code like:

```
func myMethod() {
    for n in 1...100 {
        do some stuff
        callback(parameters)
        based on some logic possibly Thread.pause
        recursively call myMethod()
    } 
}
```

My recursion works just fine but I just want to slow it down occasionally. I assume with some refactoring I could achieve the same effect but it would be so simple to just insert a quick little inline pause.

Comment: 'I was hoping I could just say sleep(0.5) but of course that would be too easy' Why would be that to easy?

Comment: Can describe the broader problem that you’re attempting to solve? I know that you’d decided on your desired approach and you just want to get that to work, but I’d wager that if you stepped back and described the broader problem, we could better advise you.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob, but I'm not looking for advice on how to rework anything. I simply want to do a pause/sleep in line. If that's not possible, then I'll refactor.

Comment: @Matt I would not be calling or executing anything after a delay. I want to just stop in place, then start back up right at the same spot.

Comment: If you want to do this, then just `Thread.sleep`. But it’s almost always the wrong approach and refactoring is likely advisable. But we can’t possibly advise you on the basis of the meager information provided.

Comment: Of course you possibly can, @rob, you just did. Also, you should save the opinion stuff (your reputation notwithstanding) and try to just answer people's questions. I asked if a pause could be done, not if you would help me refactor my code to achieve the same result. But thanks for the thread.sleep tip, though I'm not convinced it paused only the thread I called it on. Maybe so but the UI updates on the main thread did not happen.

Comment: FYI, `Thread.sleep` definitely only pauses the thread from which you called it. If you ever want to confirm that you never accidentally did this from the main thread, you can put a `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .notOnQueue(.main))` in there somewhere. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, I will keep trying for the most simple and elegant solution and report back if I find something.

Comment: By the way, if you’re finding your app freezing when you’re not explicitly blocking the main thread, make sure that that your background tasks are not, for example, exhausting the very limited number of worker threads. I also worry about your reference to recursively calling `myMethod` _inside_ the `for` loop, but I’m hoping that was just a typo introduced when you were editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to credit Rob with actually answering my question by saying to use Thread.sleep. I tried that but it didn't seem to work at first. However, as I told him, I kept trying and eventually I got it to work. Not sure exactly which "comma" or "period" actually did the trick because I tried so many variations. Bottom line is that I used `usleep` to get a finer resolution on the pause since `sleep` has to be integer seconds and I wanted less than a second. Despite the warnings about using pauses in the first place or recursing from inside a for-loop, the following code works exactly as needed:

view controller

```
    object.callback = { () -> () in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.otherView.setSomeUI()
        }
    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async() {
        if self.object.method() { print("done") }
        else { print("error") }
    }
```

object

```
private func method() -> Bool
{
    if conditionA { return true } // done
    if conditionB {
        if method() { return true }
    } else {
        for n in 1...N {
            if test() {
                self.callback?() 
                usleep(x) 
                if self.method() {
                    return true
                } else {
                    self.callback?() 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```